# appending value of type NSDate is not working

Tags: arrays, swift, datepicker, append, nsdate

I have a Date Picker in my View Controller. I want to append an array in a dictionary of type AnyObject(I also tried to create a new array only of type NSDate). The appending always fails(no error but the array stays at nil).

Here is my Code

```
var zulernen =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lernen") 
     as? [String : [AnyObject]] ?? 
     [String : [AnyObject]](
       dictionaryLiteral: ("Fach1",[]),("Thema", []),("Date",[]),("Was", [])
     )
```

Here is how I append the arrays in the dictionary:

```
    zulernen["Fach1"]?.append(Fach.text!)
    zulernen["Thema"]?.append(Thema.text!)
    zulernen["Was"]?.append(waszulernen.text!)
    zulernen["Date"]?.append(Date.date)

    defaults.setObject(zulernen, forKey: "lernen")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

The appending of all items in the dictionary works except the appending of zulernen["Date"]. Where is the issue?

```
var Stichfragen =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Stichfragen") as? [Int : [String]]  ?? [Int : [String]](dictionaryLiteral: (1,[]),(2, []),(3,[]),(4, []),(5, []))
```

and:

```
    Stichfragen[1]?.append(a.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[1]?.append(b.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[2]?.append(c.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[2]?.append(d.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[3]?.append(e.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[3]?.append(f.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[4]?.append(g.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[4]?.append(h.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[5]?.append(i.text! ?? "")
    Stichfragen[5]?.append(j.text! ?? "")
```

Comment: most probably your zulernen["Fach1"] == nil

Comment: The title states the NSDate is not working, but Fach1 is a String.

Comment: I am sorry I meant all except zulernen["Date"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data structure is confusing. If I understand correctly you actually want to store an array some kind of object that has four fields, subject, topic, task and date. Instead, you are storing four arrays that contain these fields, so to recreate an object you have to extract it from four different lists, and it is similarly complicated to create one. Removing one of these objects is even more involved, leading to all kinds of problems including the one you are encountering here.

You should instead persist an array of dictionaries representing this object, `[[String: AnyObject]]`. Note how you can be so much more concise.

```
var toStudy = defaults.objectForKey("toStudy") 
    as? [[String: AnyObject]] ?? [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

Now you can populate this data structure using code that is much more readable:

```
var homework = [String: AnyObject]()
homework["Subject"] = subjectTextField.text ?? ""
homework["Topic"] = ... // etc.
homework["Date"] = datePicker.date ?? NSDate()

toStudy.append(homework)
```

Comment: However I wonder why it also doesn't work when I used a single array for the Date.

Comment: For example, if your existing defaults object omits the key "Date", the `append` after `zulernen["Date"]?` will not be executed. The setup is the actual flaw.

Comment: In my case the key "Date"  is not omitted.

Comment: So does it work with the above setup? In your setup there could be arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Your example is not working there is an error when you append the object "homework". Also my problem with the date is not longer there. However the same appears in an dictionary of type [Int:[String]. In this case it has to do with text fields.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. The homework object is just a single dictionary, so it needs *single* square brackets. - In view of my efforts you should at least up-vote the answer.

Comment: Do think it could be a bug? I would up-vote your answer when I could.